# Java.util.date value differs between iphone and CN1 simulator using SimpleDateFormat

Tags: codenameone

Actual IPhone and Iphone CN1 Simulator values vary for my Date object, which causes me downstream errors when trying to do other formatting to them (and expecting them in a specific format).
I am using Codenameone SimpleDateFormat class to convert a string (but in an Object) of value '20180201 23:59:00' into a java.util.Date object.
My code is below:

```
    public static java.util.Date ObjectToDate(Object datestr) {
    if (datestr == null) {
        return null;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        return simpleDateFormat.parse(String.valueOf(datestr));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I place the value of my conversion into a screen field so i can verify it, using:
(have replaced the object itself with the date string that doing object.toString() returns)
    DateFormatting.ObjectToDate("20180201 23:59:00").toString()
and i get back

In Simulator:
Thu Feb 01 23:59:00 GMT 2018

And on Actual iphone i get:
1 February 2018

Why? I would have thought it would be the same format as i used the com.codename1.l10n.SimpleDateFormat class to format it.
Many thanks

Comment: They might be the same. The difference might be the way you're formatting them _when you output them_. Remember that a Date object just wraps a long value: the string you see doesn't exist until you format the Date object. A single Date object may produce both of those strings, if given two different formatting functions.

Comment: So.. what code are you using to output them? Is it just Date.toString()? Trying using a SimpleDateFormat to output in both places, using the same format.

Comment: In my debug I was doing a Date.toString() to get the value. My downstream issue is that I am handing the Date object into a json format (using gson), and then it is reaching my endpoint as a string (in a different format on the device) that then fails when I insert it into my mysql column using strtodate function (as it expects a certain format). I will take another look to see if I can spot the problem.

Comment: Ok cracked it sort of. Like you said it was how the device was outputting a Date.toString(). But the value was the same when I used converted the date to a string using SimpleDateFormat again. So I’m going to replace the toString() with the formatter, at the point not of adding it to the json string. Thanks

Comment: Yes that would explain it. There is (afaik) no contract about what Date.toString() returns. It can be a different format on different systems, with different rt.jar.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you used the `SimpleDateFormat` from the `com.codename1.l10n` package and not the one from `java.text` for better consistency between platforms.